# OPENSSL - Segmentation fault (core dumped) issue

Tags: c++, openssl

I have problem with convert string[10000] to BIGNUM[10000] in openssl. Here is the part of my code:

```
for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
    char * Bchar = new char[Bi[i].size()+1];
    copy(Bi[i].begin(), Bi[i].end(), Bchar);
    Bchar[Bi[i].size()] = '\0';
    BN_dec2bn(&BiNumber[i],Bchar); //PROGRAM CRASH
    delete [] Bchar;
}
```

after start - Segmentation fault (core dumped) issue
I work in UBUNTU 13.10.

Comment: What is BiNumber? You need to include more of the relevant code.

Comment: caps: BIGNUM *BINumber[10000];

Comment: You might want `&(BiNumber[i])` rather than `&BiNumber[i]`. Other than that there's just not enough information in this question for me, personally, to be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize `BINumber`.

```
 BIGNUM *BINumber[10000];
 memset(BINumber, 0, sizeof(BINumber));
```

In `BN_dec2bn`, if first parameter is `NULL`, it will allocate otherwise it will try to use that memory address.